Cordic Cosine function for AOA estimation. I get the PDOA estimation in terms of degree and would want to find the cosine and arcsine for the AOA
from math import atan, pi
import numpy as np
def cosine_fun(input):
    k = 1.646
    bitw = 15
    inpLUK = np.zeros(bitw + 1)

    x = 1/k
    y = 0
    z = 0

    for j in range(bitw):
        tmp = atan(2 ** -(j - 1))
        inpLUK[j] = round(tmp / pi * (2 ** bitw - 1))

    x = round(x * 2**bitw)
    y = round(y * 2 ** bitw)
    for i in range(bitw):
        if i == 0:
            tmp_x = x << 1
            tmp_y = y << 1
        else:
            tmp_x = x >> (i - 1)
            tmp_y = y >> (i - 1)
        if z > 0:
            x = x - tmp_y
            y = y + tmp_x
            z = z - inpLUK[i]
        else:
            x = x + tmp_y
            y = y - tmp_x
            z = z + inpLUK[i]

    x_out = x/2**bitw
    y_out = y/2**bitw

    return x_out, y_out, z


input_angle = 30.0
sign = 0

if input_angle >= 360:
    angle = input_angle % 360
elif input_angle < -360:
    input_angle = input_angle % -360

if input_angle > 180:
    input_angle -= 360
elif input_angle < -180:
    input_angle += 360

if input_angle > 90:
    input_angle -= 180
    sign = 1

if input_angle < -90:
    input_angle += 180
    sign = 1

angle_out = input_angle

angle_out = angle_out * (pi/180)

x, y, z = cosine_fun(angle_out)

if sign:
    x = -x
    y = -y

print("cosine({}) = {}".format(input_angle, x))

This is the code to estimate the cosine. But it does not work as expected. Could someone help me out here?!. I have to implement it either using fixed point or float.
I tried the input to be 30 degree and the output is x = 2.23 , z = 1 and y = -0.00064. But the value for cosine (30) is 0.15.

Hi. What's an AOA? What's a PDOA?

Please note that you have pasted a relatively-long piece of code, and your only explanation of it is "This is the code to estimate the cosine.". Is there anyway you can make your question more easily approachable by including less code and more explanation?

Maybe a picture of the actual geometric problem you're trying to solve could help. Then on the picture you can easily point things out: "This is the angle I want to estimate, and these are the measurements which I have".

Can you please elaborate on your last sentence? "I tried the input to be 30 degree and the output is x = 2.23 , z = 1 and y = -0.00064. But the value for cosine (30) is 0.15" What is the meaning of this "but"? What output did you expect, and why, and what output did you get instead, and what makes you think it's wrong?

Also, we currently cannot run the piece of code that you pasted, because you didn't include the relevant imports, so anyone trying it out will get error messages like "NameError: name 'np' is not defined" and "NameError: name 'atan' is not defined". Please include all the relevant imports when you paste code in a StackOverflow question, so that the code becomes closer to a [mre].
